# Does nvidia optimus work well with windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

I have a laptop that is using the Nvidia ptimus graphics card switching technology. I am wondering if this will continue to work when I upgrade to Windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both an upgrade and a fresh install of windows 8 on my laptop and it worked perfectly both times. I have an m14x like John A so I don't know where his problems came from but my computer boots without complications and supports laptop + 2 extra monitors just fine.

Comment: sigh I am still a bit skeptical, so you are telling me you are able to switch between graphics and such forth? with the use of the application that nvidia provides?

Comment: I sure can. I have the same nvidia tools that I did in windows 7. I've had not a single problem with the nvidia drivers in windows 8. Actually nvidia has released drivers specifically for windows 8 now when you go to their site for drivers

Answer (score 2):

There is no Windows 8 drivers for nVidia optimus cards, your computer will probably not boot to Windows 8 after you install the drivers or if you upgrade from Windows 7 with the drivers installed.

My m14x does not boot into Windows 8 with the Windows 7 drivers installed, the screen just flickers on and off. No safe mode, no low resolution mode, nothing. Had to do a refresh which removes all your installed applications and drivers.

Don't listen to Jonathan Reno, you might have a very terrible time. If you want to upgrade to Windows 8, uninstall the drivers first, and say goodbye to your nVidia card until they release a Windows 8 driver.

Answer (score 0):

**It's Windows!** Your graphics should work on Windows 8 after you install the drivers.